# How to display two grouped products in one product page in Magento

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, grouped-products

I have to create a grouped product page in magento in which a grouped product has engine and body parts which both are grouped products with a lot of associated products. A user should be able to click on corresponding tab which should load engine product pictures and body product pictures depending on which tab he has clicked. How can I add those 2 products in the backend, with a meaningful relation between those two products that can be used to identify the product in frontend?

Comment: Why don't you make it one bundle product instead of two grouped?

Answer (score 1):

At the bare minimum I would make them related products in the manage products pages. This way the other one will show in the right hand column when viewing the other. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-product-relations.